# Why does the compiler only generate object files .o only from .cpp files

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, header-files, object-files

as the title says : Why does the compiler only generate object files .o only from .cpp files not header files ? and how the linker knows how to link object files together if the implementation is in .h files ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the compiler only generate object files .o only from .cpp files not header files

For concreteness, I'll assume the compiler is GCC's C++ compiler.

The compiler will compile a header file to an object file, if you make
clear that's what you really want.

**header.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <iostream>

inline void hw()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

If you simply do:

```
$ g++ header.h
```

then it won't generate an object file, because it assumes from the `.h`
extension that you don't want it to. Instead, it will generate
a [*precompiled header file*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header),
`header.h.gch`.

This is a reasonable assumption because usually we don't want to compile a
header file directly to an object file. Usually, we don't want to compile a header file
directly at all, and if we do, what we want is a pre-compiled header file.

But if you actually do want `header.h` compiled to `header.o`, you can insist
on it like this:

```
$ g++ -c -x c++ header.h
```

which says: *Compile, without linking, `header.h`, treating it as a C++ source file*.
And the output is `header.o`.

This `header.o` is pretty useless, however. It does not, for instance, export the
solitary function `hw` to the linker, because the function is inlined. If we
look at the symbols in the object file:

```
$ objdump -C -t header.o

header.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 header.h
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l     O .bss   0000000000000001 std::__ioinit
0000000000000000 l     F .text  000000000000003e __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
000000000000003e l     F .text  0000000000000015 _GLOBAL__sub_I_header.h
0000000000000000 l    d  .init_array    0000000000000000 .init_array
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack    0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame  0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment   0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 std::ios_base::Init::Init()
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 .hidden __dso_handle
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 __cxa_atexit
```

we see there's nothing there but boilerplate and things pulled in by `#include <iostream>`.

We *could* make `header.h` serviceable for linkage by deleting the keyword `inline`.
Then if we recompile as before and have another look:

```
$ objdump -C -t header.o | grep hw
0000000000000061 l     F .text  0000000000000015 _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z2hwv
0000000000000000 g     F .text  0000000000000023 hw()
```

We've exported `hw()`! We can link `header.o` in a program!

**main.cpp**

```
extern void hw();

int main()
{
    hw();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile that:

```
$ g++ -c main.cpp
```

Link:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o header.o
```

Run:

```
$ ./prog
Hello World
```

*But there's a snag*. Now that we've defined `hw()` in `header.h` so that
the linker can see it, *we can't use* `header.h` *in the way that header files
are normally used any more*, i.e. we can't `#include "header.h"` in more than
one `.cpp` file that are compiled and linked together in the same program:

**main1.cpp**

```
extern void foo();
extern void bar();

int main()
{
  foo();
  bar();
  return 0;
}
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

void foo(){
    hw();
};
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

void bar(){
    hw();
};
```

Compile them all:

```
$ g++ -c main1.cpp foo.cpp bar.cpp
```

All good. So link:

```
% g++ -o prog main1.o foo.o bar.o
bar.o: In function `hw()':
bar.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `hw()'
foo.o:foo.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

No good, because `hw()` is defined twice, once in `foo.o`
and again in `bar.o`, and that's a linkage error: the
linker can't pick one definition rather than the other.

So you see that the compiler is willing and able to compile a `.h`
file as a C++ source file if you insist; it's able and willing to
compile a `.blahblah` file as a C++ source if you insist,
assumimg there is legal C++ in the `.blahblah` file. But a header
file compiled to an object file is of little or no use to us.

The distinction between `.h` file and `.cpp` file is just a conventional
distinction as to *how we intend the file to be used*. If we
give a `.h` extension we are saying: *All the C++ in this file can safely be
included in multiple translation units (`.cpp` files) that are compiled and linked
together*. If it we give it a `.cpp` extension we are saying: *At least some of the C++ in this
file can only be compiled and linked once in the same linkage.*

The `header.h` that we started with *was* a proper header file, according to this
convention. The `header.h` from which we deleted `inline` was *no longer* a header
file according to this convention. We should have renamed it to something `.cpp`,
if we don't just like confusing people.

> How the linker knows how to link object files together if the implementation is in .h files

The linker links nothing but object files and libraries. It doesn't know anything
about `.cpp` files or `.h` files: they might as well not exist as far as the linker
is concerned. There are three ways that "implementation" in a header file can get to
the linker.

**1)** The unconventional way that we just discussed: by compiling the header file
to an object file, which is linked. As you've seen, there is no *technical*
problem in doing that, though in practice it's never done.

**2)** The usual way, by `#include`-ing the header file in a `.cpp` file.

**hello.h**

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H

static char const * hw = "Hello world";

#endif
```

**hello.cpp**

```
#include "hello.h"
char const * hello = hw;
```

In this case, the compiler [*preprocesses*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor) `hello.cpp`
before it even starts to generate object code, and you can see what the compiler sees after
the preprocessor is finished by telling the compiler to do the preprocessing and nothing else:

```
$ g++ -P -E hello.cpp
static char const * hw = "Hello world";
char const * hello = hw;
```

The output of that command is the *translation unit* that will get compiled into
`hello.o`, and as you see, the code in `hello.h` is simply copied into the
translation unit in the place of `#include "hello.h"`.

So by the time the compiler starts to generate `hello.o`, the header `hello.h`
is irrelevant: it might as well not exist.

**3**) By compiling the `header.h` file into a pre-compiled `header.h.gch`. The
`header.h.gch` is a "semi-compiled" form of `header.h` that will be `#include`-ed,
if it exists, whenever `#include "header.h"` or `#include <header.h>` appears
in the code. The only difference is that the semi-compiled `header.h.gch` can
be processed faster than `header.h`: **(3)** is just a faster version of **(2)** (and it has the limitation that the compiler will only accept one precompiled header per compilation.)

Whether it gets there by **(1)**,**(2)** or **(3)**, the linkage of code
from a `.h` file is no different from the linkage of code from a `.cpp` file.
All code is compiled by the compiler. The compiler doesn't care whether code
originates in a `.h` file or `.cpp` file. The compiler generates object files,
and the linker links the object files.

Comment: Now I understand that in reality to compile a project the compiler only cares about .cpp files because half of the other job is done by the  preprocessor . and how can I use those commands with the compiler ? I'm just a beginner and I use visual studio and tank's

Comment: @MekacherAnis You can't use GCC commands with the Visual Studio compiler: they're different compilers with quite different commandline options. But there *is* a commandline compiler and linker "in behind" VC++ that you can use at the Visual Studio command prompt. Start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h.aspx)
and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx5b050y.aspx). You can also download and install GCC C++ for Windows from various sources, e.g. [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) It's open-source software.

Comment: @MekacherAnis Or you can install a basic linux-like environment on Windows:
[Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), [MSYS2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/)
and use GCC in that environment, which is a more natural enviroment to use
it in.